# C# Wpf listBox programmatical selection colour

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, listbox, selected

I have a multiple selection listbox with a set of elements.
When I select one or more of them through mouse the selected elements are clearly visibly selected since they get a dark blue background.

When I programmatically select them through:

```
lbPaths.SelectedItems.Clear();
for (int iii = 0; iii < lbPaths.Items.Count; iii+=2)
{               
    if(condition)
    {
        lbPaths.SelectedItems.Add(lbPaths.Items[iii]);
        lbPaths.SelectedItems.Add(lbPaths.Items[iii+1]);
        break;
    }
}
```

elements get a very dark pale grey which is not visible at all.
Aside from the Windows colour, what have I got to do to programmatically select listbox elements so that it's clearly visible that they're selected?

Comment: Have you tried setting focus to the listbox after the selection is done?

Comment: That's it thanx a lot!!!

Comment: You're welcome. I posted the answer so you can accept it and everyone else will know how to get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set focus to the Listbox after the selection is done.